# Gurobi, Python : How to recover the value of dual variables in a MIP

Tags: python-2.7, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I want to apply column generation method then i want to know how to recover the value of dual variables in a MIP. Please help me.

```css
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from gurobipy import *

m = Model("M1")

x = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="x")
y = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="y")
m.update()

m.addConstr(30*x + 25*y <= 2110, name="c0")
m.addConstr(12*x + 17*y >= 350, name="c1")
m.update()

m.setObjective(100*x + 25*y , GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.update()

m.optimize()

for c in m.getConstrs():
    print ('la contrainte num __%s, le cout reduit__%i')%(c.constrName,c.getAttr("Pi"))
```

Answer (score 0):

MIPs do not have dual values. You have two options:

1. Do column generation on the LP relaxation
2. Use branch-and-cut, a complex procedure that cannot be implemented easily using commercial solvers like Gurobi Optimizer or CPLEX

Comment: Thanks M.Glockner